# Map Reduce - Not able to get the rigth key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I am writing map reduce code finding the maximum temperature. The problem is that I am getting the maximum temperature but without the corresponding key.

```
public static class TemperatureReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>{

Text year=new Text();

int maxTemperature=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for(IntWritable valTemp:values) {
            maxTemperature=Math.max(maxTemperature, valTemp.get());
        }

        //System.out.println("The maximunm temperature is " + maxTemperature);
        context.write(year, new IntWritable(maxTemperature));
    }
}
```

mapper imagin like

```
1955  52
1958  7
1985  22
1999  32
```

and so on.

It is overwriting the keys and printing all the data. I want only maximum temperature and its year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of things wrong with your code sample:

1. Reset the maxTemperature inside the reduce method (as the first statement), at the moment you have a bug in that it will output the maximum temperature seen for all preceding key/values
2. Where are you configuring the contents of `year`? in fact you don't need to, just call `context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxTemperature);` as the input key is the year
3. You might want to create a IntWritable instance variable and re-use it rather than creating a new IntWritable when writing out the output value (this is an efficiency thing rather than a  potential cause of your problem)

Comment: Well thank you very much.This solved the bug. One more thing i new to Hadoop . So is there any way , my code can delete the output folder.I have to delete it manually , when i run the code.

Comment: In your driver code (the class that extends Configured and implements Tool), you can call `FileSystem.get(getConf()).delete(new Path(outputFolder), true)`, where outputFolder is the string containing you output folder name / path